# Nonreal units in totally imaginary number fields

Tags: field-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Suppose we are given a totally imaginary number field $L$ of degree greater $2$, is it possible that all units of $L$ lie in $\mathbb R$? This is true for almost all quadratic imaginary number fields, but i am not sure how to proceed in the case of higher degrees. I'd also be glad if you could point out some literature on this subject.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $L$ be a number field with a chosen complex embedding, and let $K$ be its real subfield.

If $L$ has $a$ real embeddings and $2b$ complex embeddings, then its unit rank is $a+b-1$.
If $K$ has $c$ real embeddings and $2d$ complex embeddings, then its unit rank is $c+d-1$.

Your hypothesis would require $a+b-1 = c+d-1$. However, as $[L:K] \geq 2$, we also have $a+2b \geq 2(c + 2d)$. If I've solved correctly, this implies $a=d=0$, and $b=c$.

So, the possible situation is that $K$ is a totally real number field of degree $n$, and that $L$ is a totally imaginary quadratic extension of $K$. Both of these fields have unit rank $n-1$, and so it's plausible that they have equal unit groups.

I'd imagine the conjecture would be true for nearly any example you constructed satisfying this condition.

---

I'm now at a computer where I can easily use sage. The very first thing I tried worked, just as I predicted:

```
K.<a> = NumberField(x^2 - 7)
R.<y> = PolynomialRing(K)
L.<b> = NumberField(y^2 - (a-3))
G = L.unit_group()
G <= K
```

prints `True`. Sage reports the fundamental unit of `L` is `3*a - 8`.

The field `K` is $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{7})$, and the field `L` is $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{\sqrt{7} - 3})$. The fundamental unit of $L$ is $3 \sqrt{7} - 8$.

Comment: you are right, the situation arises only in CM-extensions, but is there an example of a CM-field K of degree greater 2 with $U(K)=U(K^+)$?

Comment: thank you, that is the example i was looking for. Do you know of any literature concerning CM-fields, dealing with their units?

Comment: Sorry; the extent of my knowledge of CM-fields (aside from just basic algebraic number theory) is that CM stands for "complex multiplication". (and even that was a guess)

Comment: ok, i will try to consult Narkiewicz's book then, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3):

This is a comment to Hurkyl's answer, which is too long to fit in the comment box.

Let $K$ be a CM field, let $E$ be the group of units in $\mathcal{O}_K$, let $K^+$ be the maximal real subfield of $K$, and let $E^+$ be the unit group in $\mathcal{O}_{K^+}$. Let $W$ be the group of roots of unity in $K$. Then, $[E:WE^+]=1$ or $2$.

You can find a proof in Washington's "Introduction to Cyclotomic Fields", Theorem 4.12.

In your case, you want $E=E^+$, so you need $W\subseteq E^+$ (and so $W=\{\pm 1\}$). In general all one can say is that if $W=\{\pm 1\}$, then $[E:E^+]=1$ or $2$.